# How can this stock have an intra-day range of more than 90% on 24Aug2015?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-analysis, volatility

I am looking at this stock BKCC and was shocked at one point at its price of only $0.97. Just within 1 hour of opening, BKCC traded between $0.97 and $9.5.

How can this be so, particularly when it is actually quite liquid? The market cap is $6b. Not a penny stock prone to manipulation. Can someone explain? I am shell-shocked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT**: It was [System Disruption or Malfunctions](http://www.streetinsider.com/General+News/Blackrock+Capital+Investment+%28BKCC%29+Trades+Canceled+Below+$5.86Share/10838630.html)

> August 24, 2015 2:12 PM EDT
>   Pursuant to [Rule 11890(b)](https://www.sec.gov/rules/sro/nd9651f.htm) NASDAQ, on [its own motion](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=clearlyerroneous), in conjunction
>   with BATS, and FINRA has determined to **cancel** all trades in security
>   Blackrock Capital Investment. (Nasdaq: BKCC) **at or below $5.86** that
>   were executed in NASDAQ between 09:38:00 and 09:46:00 ET. This
>   decision cannot be appealed. NASDAQ will be canceling trades on the
>   participants behalf.

A person on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/comments/3i8ghs/) claimed that he was the buyer. He used [Robinhood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtQHk.png), a $0 commission broker and start-up.

The canceled trades are reflected on CTA/UTP and the current charts will differ from the one posted below.

---

It is an undesired effect of the 5-minute Trading Halt.

It is not "within 1 hour of opening, BKCC traded between $0.97 and $9.5".

Those trades only occurred for **a few seconds** on **two occasions**.

One possible reason is that when the trading halt ended, there was a lot of Market Order to sell accumulated.

Refer to the following chart, where each candle represents a 10 second period. As you can see, the low prices did not **"sustain"** for hours.

[image: Chart]

And the published halts.

[image: Halts]

Comment: So the volume traded at the abnormally low price was 90-some k, representing less than a million dollars in losses to the seller(s). They've probably had worse days.

Comment: @base64 - Nice chart and explanation. Isn't there an implication this is a result of a *market order*? If every owner simply had orders in place, say no lower than $8, that odd dramatic drop wouldn't have occurred.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Without subscribing to Historical Order Book data such as NASDAQ Market Replay PLUS, I cannot tell the exact cause. It could be everybody's stop loss being triggered; it could be market maker withdrawing. I am not familiar with how the opening price of a resumption is determined (opening cross auction vs price-time priority). https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/ProductsServices/Trading/IPOHalt/haltcross_fs.pdf

Comment: I saw the edit. Nice work. Still, even though wrong, I like my answer, too.

Comment: A follow-up question was asked in response to your answer. Thanks. Good answer.

http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52292/if-a-stock-is-sold-but-the-purchase-was-canceled-by-the-exchange-will-it-be-con

Answer (score 8):

As you know, the market is in turmoil today. At this moment, 11:45 am, the S&P is down 2.3%, 45 points. But, premarket, it was down 100 points.

Now, premarket, I heard Jim Cramer say, "today is not the day to use market orders." Yes, on Mad Money, he seems a bit eccentric, but he does offer some wise advice at times.

In my opinion, your stock had some people that did just that. A market order. And, regardless of the fundamentals of this company, buyers had no orders to buy. Except a couple wise guys (in both senses) that put in buys at crazy prices. And they filled.

With an Apple, trading around $100, the book probably has millions of shares on order with a buy at $80 or higher. Just an example. I'd bet there were a number of stocks that had the profile of yours, i.e. a chart reflecting trades similar to a flash crash. There are some traders smiling ear to ear, and some crying in their beer.

(Note - I use the phrase "in my opinion." This is the only explanation I can imagine. Occam's Razor.)